# TestNG - How can I re-run failed tests after the complete of the suite

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testng

How can I re-run failed tests after the completion of the suite in TestNG.
Using RetryAnalyzer I can re-run the failed test cases immediately after the failed test case but not after suite completion.

The reason why I require this:
My test cases run in parallel on 20+ threads, some of my test-systems misbehave on this load so retrying immediatly after doesn't help much.

But we retry the failed test cases by re-running the testNG-failed.xml, these cases are passed. Currently, we are re-running the testNG-failed.xml but it creates 2 reports and many other problems for us. Can we achieve the similar functionality without re-running the testNG-failed.xml, through RetryAnalyzer or any other way in testNG?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `suiteListener` that shows failed test cases after test suite has run like below to get all failed test cases for all contexts

```
public class suiteListener implements ISuiteListener {


    @Override
public void onStart(ISuite suite) {

}

     @Override
        public void onFinish(ISuite suite) {

              System.out.println("suite finished");
            final Map<java.lang.String,ISuiteResult>  res = suite.getResults()       
                    for (ISuiteResult r : res.values()) {
                             context =  r.getTestContext()  ;           
                    Iterator<ITestResult> failedTestCases =context.getFailedTests().getAllResults().iterator();
                    while (failedTestCases.hasNext()) {
                     System.out.println("failedTestCases...");
                     ITestResult failedTestCase = failedTestCases.next();
                     ITestNGMethod method = failedTestCase.getMethod();
                    java.lang.String testName =    failedTestCase.getName();

                       System.out.println("failed method.."+ method);   
                       System.out.println("failed testName.."+ testName);   
                    }
                }
```

}

And attach listener to `testng.xml` file

```
<listeners>
      <listener class-name ="firsttestngpackage.suiteListener" />
 </listeners>
```

Then you can simply utilize [this](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically) method to run your tests programmatically by creating a virtual class

Modify suite like this with [`IAlterSuiteListener`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.11/org/testng/IAlterSuiteListener.html)  and add listener in your `testng.xml`

```
import org.testng.IAlterSuiteListener;
import org.testng.xml.XmlPackage;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SimpleSuiteAlterer implements IAlterSuiteListener {
    @Override
    public void alter(List suites) {
        XmlSuite suite = suites.get(0);
        XmlTest xmlTest = new XmlTest(suite);
        xmlTest.setName("test123");

         XmlClass xmlClass = new XmlClass("yourClass");
        List<XmlInclude> includeMethods = new ArrayList<>();
        includeMethods.add(new XmlInclude("your_method1"));
         includeMethods.add(new XmlInclude("your_method2"));

         //add more methods dynamically from your other listener

         xmlClass.setIncludeMethods(includeMethods);
         xmlTest.setXmlClasses(classes) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think running this test suite will run a separate suite and I will get another report.  or it will update the existing test suite and test cases results?

Comment: @ Nikunj Aggarwal I edited above to answer your query. Please do not forget to mark answer and upvote

Comment: ok let me analyze ur approach and then will upvote and accept the answer. Thanks for the help

Comment: @NikunjAggarwal I have the same question. Where you able to resolve using RetryAnalyzer?